# Messagebox without buttons in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to handle exception in C#...suppose if the program writes to an output file it checks for if file already exists then it should display an error message.

I don't want to use `MessageBox.Show()` as it comes with an OK button.
    I want to use some kinda informational message where user doesnot have to click on any ok button.
    any suggestions???

Thank you

Comment: If the user doesn't have to click an ok button, how is he going to make your window go away?

Comment: Are you restricted to Windows.Forms, or can you use WPF? There's a Popup class in the WPF framework where you can define your own contents.

Comment: What are you using? Winforms, WPF, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for a Toast message that shows a notification, then disappears after a short time by itself.

An example for this is shown [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c10139/Form-Fade-InOut-Effect-and-Notification-Window.htm).