# Dialog box after form submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms, modal-dialog

I searched all day for the right answer on stackoverflow, also I couldn't find something helping me out.

Having a simple form like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button value="Login" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);"></button>
</form>
```

**currently:** Submitting the form redirects to process.php showing a success message & redirecting to another page after some time.

**What I need:** instead of redirecting to process.php a modal dialog box should open doing the work and showing a success message, closing the dialog box after some time and then doing a refresh of the actual side.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ajax submit, JQuery already supports this. Try JQuery API http://api.jquery.com/ especially http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ Examples are provided on that site too.

Comment: Here Here! This should be enough to get you started. Come back when you get stuck!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

[Message Box opens then disappears](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c10139/Form-Fade-InOut-Effect-and-Notification-Window.htm)

There is also a similar question here on stackoverflow: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959207/messagebox-without-buttons-in-c-sharp)